# Laravel: Marathi (मराठी) language not displaying correctly in "BLADE PHP OR PHP" file

Tags: php, laravel, translation, laravel-blade

we are developing one application in Marathi language for farmers, but i have faced one issue after start conversion from "*HTML to Blade PHP Template*".

My HTML template showing Marathi (मराठी) language correctly, but after I had change the file extension from .html to .blade.php Marathi language change to "?????? ??? ????".

I have already added UTF-8 in my head tag. I am not getting what is the problem exactly related to?

I am adding Marathi text by using "*Google Input tool*"

HTML Template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

</head>
<body class="blank">

<div class="back-link">
    <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-primary">मुख पृष्ठावर जा</a>
</div>
<div class="text-center m-b-md">
    <h3>कृपया अनुप्रयोग लॉगिन करा</h3>
    <small>अनुप्रयोग करण्या साठी लॉगिन करा.</small>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Blade PHP template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

</head>
<body class="blank">

<div class="back-link">
    <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-primary">??? ???????? ??</a>
</div>
<div class="text-center m-b-md">
    <h3>????? ????????? ????? ???</h3>
    <small>????????? ?????? ???? ????? ???.</small>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this problem is related to laravel server? which we run on port 8000? because apache support UTF-8 encode decode perfectly. is it possible?

Comment: Language is not displaying??

Comment: Marathi language auto converted. `मुख पृष्ठावर जा` to `????? ??? ??`. Its showing correctly when it is in .html file. If i have change .blade.php to .html again then marathi showing correctly but not in .blade.php

Comment: download krutidev or any marathi font , Add `font-family` and `src` to you div element.

Comment: how you are calling the pages in blade.php

Comment: @Sona from my controller which is in `app\Http\Controllers\Auth` and my view is in `resources\views`.

Comment: no i mean am asking how you are calling assets pages,css,js pages??

Comment: @Sona `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('vendor/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css') }}" />` is this really related to my question?

Comment: Are you saying that you just changed the extension from .html to .php and the issue happened? And the issue is happened in your editor or in the browser?

Comment: @haitran
First condition
.html template showing Marathi correctly in both editor and in browser also.
Second
If I change .html file to .php it converts marathi to ????? in both editor and browser also.
Third
If same thing i have update any HTML file with marathi language it's showing perfectly, in both.

Comment: Then, I'd suggest you check the file encoding (charset) to make sure it's UTF-8;